# D3js and React regarding DOM manipulations

Tags: javascript, dom, d3.js, reactjs, virtual-dom

How does D3 dom-manipulation mechanism influence (if any at all) on React's virtual-dom?

I've found many examples show that both libraries can work together great, but none of them refer to this issue..
It might not be an issue at all btw, it's just a big question that I raised, but couldn't find an answer for.

**EDIT:**

I've just learned that only when "writing" to the virtual-dom, the dom get's updated. and ALWAYS when "reading" from the actual "reading" is done on the virtual-dom.

So when I use D3 to update the DOM directly, the virtual-dom has no idea about it, and I won't be able to read the new changes from the virtual-dom.
That's what I was afraid of, and now I wonder how React's helping me when I have to use D3?

Comment: FYI, I put together a list of approaches: https://gist.github.com/chroth7/a56fafed1efc43737d11 Please note that there are many other ideas around (if you find any, please do let me know), depending on the context of your project! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You follow the rules of each when interacting with them. With regard to react, you wrap the d3 dom manipulation in a component, and that's it.

Depending on the components you use, you can either have components that do everything in d3, or [write some primitives](https://busypeoples.github.io/post/d3-with-react-js/) which allow you to use react components instead of low level d3.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I don't see how it answers my question sir, If I use D3 directly, how does it influence on react's virtual-dom? does the virtual-dom sync's on the new-changed dom? what actually happens in such case?

Comment: It's entirely separate from the virtual dom.